# Problem headers mail php

Tags: php, email, header

I sending a message with this code below and works:

```
$headers = 'From: Online <'.$emailTo.'>\r\n'; 
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$emailTo.'\r\n';
$headers .= 'Return-Path: Online <'.$emailTo.'>\r\n';
$headers .= "Bcc: email@hotmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: email@gmail.com\r\n";
```

The problem is When I click in Reply on the email appear like this in the field to:

**Online \r\nReply-To: email@server.com.au\r\nReturn-Path: Online \r\nBcc: email@hotmail.com**

Any idea that can help me?
Cheers M

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but you would be better off using famous libraries like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer so you do not have to worry about these things. Will edit my answer later if I find a solution to your problem.  @Pekka: Thanks for pointing it out. Migrated it now to a comment

Comment: It doesn't make sense to put in `Return-Path:` and the syntax you have for that field is wrong.  You should probably take Rolando's advice and use an existing library if you are not planning on becoming an email expert first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\r` and `\n` must be enclosed in double quotes, in single quoted strings [they are taken literally](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).